# Wall Paper Changer Not Working Correctly

Tags: python, windows, urllib2, ctypes, wallpaper

I am new to Python and I encountered a problem when I was making a program that would change my background to the Nation Geographic Picture of the Day. It gets the path to the jpeg just fine, but when I use the command to change the desktop background (for Windows) it just changes the background to a solid black. The code itself doesn't throw any errors, it is just not working how I wound want it to. Here is the code.

```
import urllib2
import ctypes

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/")
code = url.readlines()
pos = code[1303].split("\"",2)
imgurl = pos[1]
print imgurl
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, imgurl , 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure it can take a URL? Have you tried downloading the file and giving it the path to the local version?

Comment: Yes, I think you're going to have to actually retrieve the image, I doubt Windows is going to do that for you!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be passing a URL to the set wallpaper command, not a path to an image.  Fetch the image first.  Try it like this instead.

```
import urllib2
import ctypes

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/")
code = url.readlines()
pos = code[1303].split("\"",2)
imgurl = pos[1]

print imgurl
# Changes after here
url2 = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)
out = open("wallpaper.jpg", "wb")
out.write(url2.read())
out.close()
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "wallpaper.jpg" , 0)
```

I haven't actually tried that (not running on windows) so maybe it will fix the problem and maybe not!

PS that is really fragile code for parsing the url out but kudos for getting it working!

Comment: Thanks! It now works just fine. Also, I know it is kind of shaky code, but I really didn't know how else to do it LOL.

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to parse the url is indeed very fragile. You would be better of using a regex. This regex searches for the unique div containing the image and then removes everything but the url.
Also, using `with` to open a file is better, because it automatically closes the file.
The improved code would then be:

```
import urllib2
import ctypes
import re

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://photography.nationalgeographic.com/photography/photo-of-the-day/")
code = url.read()
imgurl = re.sub(r'(.|\n)+?<div class="primary_photo">(.|\n)+?<img src="(.+?)"(.|\n)+', r'\3', code)

print imgurl
url2 = urllib2.urlopen(imgurl)
with open("wallpaper.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(url2.read())
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "wallpaper.jpg" , 0)
```